# Unallocated data type in allocated struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Say I have a struct definition like this :

```
typedef struct Sample
{
    int s;
}Sample;
```

And I declare a pointer variable like below

```
Sample *sample = (Sample *)malloc(sizeof(Sample));
```

Now my question is, where does this 'int s' placed, in stack or heap? I mean is there dynamic memory allocation for 'int s' also?

Comment: It allocates a chunk of memory on the heap large enough for a `Sample`. Assuming you actually place a `Sample` there, that `int` is contained within it. Only 1 allocation. (And in this case, it will be the same size as just an `int`).

Comment: Memory is allocated on the heap with the size of a Sample object. s is a data member of any sample object, so yes it is on heap. (BTW, since this question is tagged with both C++ and C, just FYI you should use new instead of malloc in C++)

Comment: So can I free only 'int s', not the entire sample object? if so, how to?

Comment: you can only pass to `free()` what you received from `malloc()` or `calloc()` or `realloc()`  the code does not receive `s` from `malloc()`  it did receive a pointer that was placed into `sample`, so only `sample` can be passed to `free()`

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, 1) in C, do not cast the returned value, its' type is already a `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate space for a `struct` via `malloc`, the entire `struct` (i.e. all fields contained within the `struct`) live on the heap.

Comment: The official name for _heap_ is _dynamic storage_ IIRC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As the whole memory is taken from the heap, can I free 'int s' somehow?

Comment: @Abdulkadir No, you can free part of the struct.  You can only pass to `free` what was passed to `malloc`.  So you can't `free(&sample->s)`, you can only `free(sample)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you dynamically allocate memory, it is always taken from heap. I guess this concludes the answer